# Cors Error 'Access Control Allow Origin' while calling .net core web api from .net core mvc

Tags: c#, .net, ajax

I am getting a cors error of allow access control origin while calling my .NET Core API with a jwt token authentication. When I remove authorization from controller there no more access origin error. Any help will be appreciated.

This is my code:

Ajax call from `https://localhost:44354`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://localhost:44325/Home',
    headers: { Authorization:'Bearer'+ localStorage.getItem('token')},
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonP',
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Error!');
    }
});
```

Web API controller method:

```
[Authorize(Roles = UserRoles.Admin)]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> Get()
    {
        var heroes = new List<HeroInfo>();
    }
}
```

My `startup` class, `ConfigureService` method:

```
var origins = new string[] { "https://localhost:44354" };
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p => p
            .WithOrigins(origins)
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .WithHeaders("content-type", "authorization") 
            .AllowCredentials()
        ));
```

This is the `Role` class:

```
public static class UserRoles
{
    public const string Admin = "Admin";
    public const string User = "User";
}
```

When I remove the `Authorization` annotation from the ajax call then there will be no cors error.

I use "JsonP" as datatype as it is cross domain but it's not working.

Comment: Remove your `.WithHeaders` call, it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

By Adding AllowAnonymous attribute to my controller with Authorize attribute that help me to fix the issue.

```
       [Authorize(Roles = UserRoles.Admin)]
       [AllowAnonymous]
       public class AccountController : Controller {}
```